# Where is the question which lists Game Development SE questions with funny titles?

Tags: support

I could not find the link for the above!

Comment: "Funny Titles" is subjective, I doubt there is one.

Comment: We hate fun. There isn't such a link.

Comment: It's possible you are confusing this site with the meta for *gaming*.stackexchange.com? That site is more prone to "funny" question titles and may maintain such a list on their meta.

Comment: Yeah, I was, sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: Eh, I guess I'll self-flag this so someone can delete it haah

Comment: According to a moderator at Arqade, they used to have such a question but deleted it because they also hate fun. The best you're likely to get is [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2187/the-memes-of-arqade-and-its-chat/2196#2196) (thanks to fredley and Wipqozn).

Comment: Man! What a tragedy! But thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any such post on Meta. Further, I don't see a reason to maintain such a list, so I'm not sure why such a question would exist in the future.